# How to protect a file in the git repository from commits after ther first commit?

Tags: git

I have a `tracking.properties` file under my Java app classpath, which can change every moment like "seq=10" to "seq=17".

The property file is now put into github repository. I hope that the file exists in the repository so that other developers can clone it and that the file be not pushed by them because the "seq" can change from user to user.

I tried

```
git rm --cached -f <file>
```

then add `tracking.properties` to .gitignore, but it results in deleteing the property file in the git repository. It should remain there and only ONCE-FOR-ALL commit be allowed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the "template" pattern for this.

Check the file in as `tracking.properties.template` and add `tracking.properties` to your `.gitignore`.  Then, after checking out the repository, developers should copy the template file to `tracking.properties` and then edit it as they wish.  This file will be ignored, and so the file will not show up as dirty and developers will be unlikely to commit changes to it.

This will not prevent the template file from changing, but that could be a good thing -- you might need to make changes to it in the future.  The important thing is that local-only changes to `tracking.properties` are possible without too much confusion.

Comment: That's nice for developers, surely. But my app is expected to be cloned(github has no download button any more, so clone) from also non-developers and I would rather not force them to copy and rename a file as possible...  Is there any other more automatic method?

Comment: @linzhixing If they need to change something in the file anyway, then it's not much more to document.  Git doesn't have a concept for "tracked file that doesn't change" -- a file is either tracked or it is not.  If there is some kind of setup script then you could have the script take care of making the copy.  Otherwise, you could document the step.

Comment: Thanks! I finally included cp command in the seup shell script.

Answer (score 10):

If each developer runs this command after cloning the repo

```
git update-index --skip-worktree tracking.properties
```

then git will forever after treat the file as if it had not changed locally, even when it has.

If you ever do need to commit local changes to it, you can turn it back to normal like this

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree tracking.properties
```

Yet another alternative is

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged tracking.properties
```

[Here is a good explanation of the subtle differences between skip-worktree and assume-unchanged](http://fallengamer.livejournal.com/93321.html). I think skip-worktree is better for you, since it ignores `reset --hard` and preserves the flag when the upstream version has changed.

Comment: Just for completeness, revert operation for `--assume-unchanged` is `--no-assume-unchanged`.